# setting some colors of ggplot with the same colour and get rid of labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a much larger `dataframe` but I post here a tow example for reproducibility.

```
df = data.frame(fc_col = c(rep('apple',3),rep('orange',3),rep('banana',3)),var1 = c(rep(1:3,3)),var2 = c(20,10,5,30,15,2,40,27,8))
```

If I plot:

```
> ggplot(data=df, aes(x=var1, y=var2,colour = fc_col))+
+     geom_line()
```

I get this:

[image]

I would like to get something like `apple` to **black** and `banana` `orange` to a single color say **blue**. Imagine there are not 3 levels of factor `fc_col` like in this case but 300. I would also like to get rid of the label `banana` `orange` and write a single one say `fruits` and have it there with the blue color as mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may helps.

The trick is, keep `fc_col` that keeps fruits themselves, will be used as `group` in `aes()`. And make another variable `new_fac` for `color` argument .

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  mutate(new_fac = ifelse(fc_col == "apple", fc_col, "fruits") %>% as.factor()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(var1, var2, colour = new_fac, gruop = fc_col)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "blue"))
```

[image]

## `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- setDT(df)[,new_fac := ifelse(fc_col == "apple", "apple", "fruits")][]
ggplot(df2, aes(var1, var2, colour = new_fac, gruop = fc_col)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "blue"))
```

Comment: ok are you modifying the dataframe with `mutate` ? how are the lines being kept if by the time you plot there are only two levels of factor `new_fac`

Comment: @moth In `aes` part, `color` is from `new_fac` and `group` is from `fc_col`.

Comment: ok cool, I wonder if there is a `data.table` approach to that since the pipe `%>%` is feeding directly to the ggplot command

Comment: @moth in R base it would be `df$fc_col_new <- ifelse(df$fc_col == "apple", "apple", "fruits")`

Comment: oh yes `data.table` here https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/fifelse.html

Comment: @moth I add `data.table` version code. I'm not sure if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: for the posterity, the key of this answer is the `group` aesthetic, and create a new column for the color aesthetic

Comment: @Park that's good thanks. maybe if you add two lines about the explicit `group` aesthetic it may help others, I didn't know about it but now I know

Comment: @moth I add little explanation about it. :D